# Accessing localhost with data sent from game (War Thunder)

Tags: beautifulsoup, port, urllib

While playing the game War Thunder if you use the address http://localhost:8111 you can access a website that shows the current parameters of your plane that you are flying.

I want to access this data and automatically export it into files. For example the power performance of the engine at certain heights.

I use beautiful soup and urllib to access the data. However I have no clue how to send the data from my game with it. Without that however the website does not show any data.

Does anyone have an idea how I can send this data with my request?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your script in Python, you can use [this module](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/WarThunder_Telemetry). Once you have the data, you can write out the data like so:

```
with open('logger.txt','a') as outFile:
    outFile.writelines(data)
```

Obviously, it'll take more effort to get things working, but it's a good start.